# Typescript interface array as class member

Tags: typescript

**class member as interface array**

what's wrong with my code i don't understand why this.circles.length is undefine

```
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
interface Circle {
  xy: Point;
  radius: number;
}

class Canvas {
  circles: Circle[]; //**interface Circle as Canvas member**
  constructor() {
    this.circles.push({
      xy: {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
      },
      radius: 0,
    });

    console.log(this.circles.length); //error
  }
}
```

Comment: You declared it but haven't initialised it anywhere

Comment: Just initialize `this.circles`: Change `circles: Circle[];` to `circles: Circle[] = [];` ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkK7PW))

Answer (score 0):

You need to create/ initialize the array first. You can initialize it with one element already in the array like this:

```js
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

interface Circle {
  xy: Point;
  radius: number;
}

class Canvas {
  circles: Circle[]; //**interface Circle as Canvas member**

  constructor() {
    this.circles = [{ // create and initialize array with one member
      xy: {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
      },
      radius: 0,
    }];

    console.log(this.circles.length); // prints "1"
  }
}

new Canvas()
```

Expected output:

```
1
```

An equivalent implementation of the `constructor()` doing the above in two steps would look like this:

```js
constructor(){
    this.circles = [];
    this.circles.push({
      xy: {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
      },
      radius: 0,
    });
    console.log(this.circles.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because Typescript is just a type system, you still need to do JS stuff to make it work properly.

```js
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

class Canvas {
  circles: Circle[] = []; // add an empty array here
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.circles.length); // it should work now
  }
}
```

---

### Why?

Look by this example instead. Since Typescript is just a type system, all the types will be wiped out when you compile it to Javascript.

```js
// typescript
let circle: Circle;

// compiled to javascript
let circle; // have no value (undefined)
```

And so is the array.

```js
// typescript
let circles: Circle[];

// compiled to javascript
let circles; // have no value (undefined)
```

That's why you can't `.push()` or `.length` because it is undefined.